# void * assignement from C to CPP

Tags: c++, c

I'm wondering why this code works in C and not in C++

```
void* dum;
dum = "dum";
```

I have the C++ error

```
In function 'int main()':
8:10: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
```

Any C++ equivalent?

Comment: `Any C++ equivalent?` -> `const void* dum; dum = "dum";`.

Comment: "*I'm wondering why this code works in C and not in C++*" - because C is less strict then C++ when it comes to const correctness and assignments to/from `void*`

Answer (score 5):

> I'm wondering why this code works in C and not in C++

It doesn't work in C++ because string literal is an array of const char.

> Any C++ equivalent?

```
const char* dum = "dum";
```

Comment: Best to use that in C too

Answer (score 1):

```
    void* dum;
    dum = (void *)"dum";
```

```
    const void* dum = "dum";
```

```
    const char* dum = "dum";
```

```
    const char* dum;
    dum = "dum";
```

```
    const void* dum;
    dum = "dum";
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation of why these code snippets work? Or at least mention that they are all viable solutions.

Comment: `void* dum; dum = (void *)"dum";` - C style casts should be avoided in C++, use C++ style casts instead. `void* dum; dum = const_cast<char*>("dum");` would be a more appropriate statement. But casting the `const` off of a string literal is very questionable, except when it is absolutely needed when interacting with legacy C code.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to cast it back to get the result you want.

String literals have type `const char*`  so your pointer would need to be `const`also. You cannot assign something that is const to a pointer to non const.

```
const void* dum = "dum";
cout << static_cast<const char*>(dum);
```

Try this `cout`without the cast to see what you get. It would be interpreted as a void pointer...

Comment: "*String literals have type `const char*`*" - actually, they have type `const char[N]`, which *decays* into `const char*` when assigned to a pointer